# Issue with Google API People :: AddContact

Tags: php, google-api, google-people-api

I have implemented the Google API in PHP as a service and using the Google_Service_ServicePeople() to add a contact. That works and I am getting back a proper result as a paople object. In addition when I call the people_connections->listPeopleConnections method I am getting back the contacts that I have created in my tests. However, when I go to contacts.google.com no contact will be shown.

Maybe it is a missunderstanding from my site, but I thought that based on the appsettings on my account, the new contacts will be created (added) to my account, won't they?

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName ('VABS-CONTACT-TEST');
$client->setAuthConfig($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/classes/Google/auth.json');
$client->addScope (Google_Service_Peopleservice::CONTACTS);

$peopleService = new Google_Service_PeopleService($client);

$person = new Google_Service_PeopleService_Person();
$name = new Google_Service_People_Name();
$name->setDisplayName ('FirstName LastName');
$name->setFamilyName ('LastName');
$name->setGivenName('FirstName');

$email = new Google_Service_People_EmailAddress();
$email->value = 'xxx@xxx.xx';

$person->setNames ($name);
$person->setEmailAddresses ($email);

$result = $peopleService->people->createContact ($person);
```

The response looks like:

```
Google_Service_PeopleService_Person Object
(
[collection_key:protected] => userDefined
[addressesType:protected] => Google_Service_PeopleService_Address
[addressesDataType:protected] => array
[ageRange] => 
[ageRangesType:protected] => Google_Service_PeopleService_AgeRangeType
[ageRangesDataType:protected] => array
[biographiesType:protected] => Google_Service_PeopleService_Biography
[biographiesDataType:protected] => array
[birthdaysType:protected] => Google_Service_PeopleService_Birthday
[birthdaysDataType:protected] => array
[braggingRightsType:protected] => Google_Service_PeopleService_BraggingRights
[braggingRightsDataType:protected] => array
[coverPhotosType:protected] => Google_Service_PeopleService_CoverPhoto
[coverPhotosDataType:protected] => array
[emailAddressesType:protected] => Google_Service_PeopleService_EmailAddress
[emailAddressesDataType:protected] => array
[etag] => %Eh8BAgMEBQYHCAkKCwwNDg8QERITFBUWFzUZNDciJScuGgwBAgMEBQYHCAkKCwwiDFFrVXd2SnRpTFZZPQ==
[eventsType:protected] => Google_Service_PeopleService_Event
[eventsDataType:protected] => array
[gendersType:protected] => Google_Service_PeopleService_Gender
```

.
.
.
.
     (
        )

```
[modelData:protected] => Array
    (
        [metadata] => Array
            (
                [sources] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [type] => CONTACT
                                [id] => 494c65970e1a12eb
                                [etag] => #QkUwvJtiLVY=
                                [updateTime] => 2018-04-04T13:58:27.710001Z
                            )
```

...

Using the

```
$peopleService->people_connections->listPeopleConnections('people/me',$options)
```

lists all the created contacts as expected.

But on my contacts.google.com page no contact will be shown. I am logged in as the same user I have created and granted access to the API.

Any ideas, hwy the contacts won't be shonw on contacts.google.com?

Many thanks!

Comment: Your understanding is correct that the contacts should show up in contacts.google.com. Are you sure the account you authorized in OAuth is the same as the one you are using to view contacts.google.com? If you have multiple accounts signed in, it's possible contacts.google.com is showing you a different account.

Another thing to try, is try using the API explorer and see if you run into the same problems https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/createContact.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. I checked it several times that the user is correctly logged in. Also using different browsers doesn't work. I also see the API calls in the API console logged in with the appropriate user.
But switch to contacts.google.com on the same page on the same browser logged in as the same user doesn't show me the contacts....
I also added a new user on contacts.google.com and it won't be shown in the list when I use the PHP script. I also recreate a new service account in the API management page. Without any success to see the contacts then...very strange

Comment: How are you "checking" that the user is the same? Perhaps one thing you can try is get the profile for the logged in user using [People API get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) for "people/me". Verify that the email, photo, and name match your account in contacts.google.com

Comment: Looking at your code, the fact that you are using "setAuthConfig" seems to indicate that you are using a service account, which won't have access to your Google account, it's tied to your project. See https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts

Comment: I checked that the logged user under contacts.google.com is the same for that I have created the service account. On your provided link there is a text saying that a service account can either work as a ressource as well as an identity. Mabye it is still a missunderstanding from my site as I never used OAuth2 before. All what I want is sending a (new) contact requests in an ajax call to the appropriate Google account. Using the API console pops up a window where I need to grant access to my contacts that I cant use in PHP. Therefore I was thinking to use a service account. Maybe I am wrong. TX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tries it wasn't possible for me to get it solved. Therefore I have tried it now via the [RapidWeb](https://github.com/rapidwebltd/php-google-people-api) Solution. Now it is working and "the setup" with a guide - even though it tooks also 3 steps of getting the right account in place - is simple. 
The main problem I had is to understand the logfic of OAuth2 and their possibilities to setup the correct OAuth2 Client. 
In my case I needed to setup a Native Client (just choose "Other" as ApplicationType on the second screen in the Google API Console after creating a new OAuth2 ClientId)

Anyway. Many thanks for all who tried to help me! Much appreciated!

Cheers!